# Android Emulator for testing of mobile application

Tags: android, testing, apk

Which Android Emulator is best for testing of mobile application by uploading APK?
I am new to mobile application testing please help me out.

Comment: above marshamallow device

Comment: Try to test it on real device, as some issues occurs only in that. But if you still want to test it on emulator then use Genymotion with highest API level.

Comment: ok thank you priyanka

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know how to use Android Emulators see the following:

[Run apps on the Android Emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator)

> Which Android Emulator is the best for testing a mobile application

This depends on your target audience, I suggest a version not to new and a version that's used a lot:

The most used android version is (according to [Most Popular Android Versions In July 2018](https://fossbytes.com/most-popular-android-versions-always-updated/) )

**Nougat Android 7.0, 7.1** (currently)

Hope this helps and good luck with Android Development